# Kudan AR Toolkit not working for Windows

Tags: 3d, kudan, android-augmented-reality

I want to add my 3D Model to the scene and used the ARToolkit for Windows to convert my .fbx object into the .armodel type.

But when I click on "Convert" the only thing that happens is a window opening for a millisecond. There is no new file in the "Save Location" and no error messages.

I am using the latest Toolkit for Windows which is provided on the homepage. The marker converter of the toolkit is working fine. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Did u get the solution?